# Can I get video cache from broswer using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

Is that possible to get cache when playing video tag according timestamp or something else? It's ok if there is no data sometimes.

Comment: if you don't want data from the cache, what do you want?

Comment: sorry, I misspell words.

Comment: it wasn't a spelling issue, it was a clarity of concept issue

Comment: Are you trying to read the `.currentTime` of  `<video>` element?